# Interactive notepad equation editor and solver?

Tags: math-software

I'm looking for an interactive equation editor like [SwiftCalcs](https://www.swiftcalcs.com/) to interactively solve various engineering equations that come up but that doesn't charge on a monthly bases and if possible preferably running locally if anyone happen to come across such a thing.

I am aware of matlab but it's not intuitive or makes the equations readable or allows for nice easy GUI
integration to manipulate variable values...

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Years ago I used Mathcad

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do much without climbing a learning curve.  Sagemath has considerable symbolic+numeric capability that can be installed on your desktop computer or accessed online free of charge.  In general Math.SE does not treat software recommendations as on-topic, though questions about "software that mathematicians use" are on-topic when tied to a specific mathematical problem.  Your post does not have such a nexus.  You might see what related content already exists at [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Coming to terms with Matlab may be the best option

Comment: Well thanks first of all, sageMath looks promising looking into it right now and thanks for the software recommendation thread link hardmath I was actually looking for it and couldn't find it I'll try there if I wont find sagemath appealing. and about matlab I'd rather concentrate on python and have a much more flexible calculator after all they are both simple programming languages and python is just more flexible